# FromJoomla MySQL Query with where condition on external database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a problem to query a field (avatarurl) from a database.
Its in joomla module from external database.
I can connect but i see only all avatarsurls (images)

```
<?php



if (!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')) {
echo 'Keine Verbindung zu mysql';
exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('3d', $link)) {
echo 'Konnte Schema nicht selektieren';
exit;
}

$sql    = ' SELECT avatarurl FROM users WHERE username = 'username')' ;
```

$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

```
if (!$result) {
echo "DB Fehler, konnte die Datenbank nicht abfragen\n";
echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<img src='";
echo $row['avatarurl'];
echo "' height='100'     width='100' >";
}

mysql_free_result($result);



?>
```

i tried to get the username from the mod_login.
here is the login greeting code

echo JText::sprintf('MOD_LOGIN_HINAME', htmlspecialchars($user->get('name')));

but doesnt works in the where query

need some help

So the Question is how can i query the avatarurl field where the username was greets

Comment: $sql    = 'SELECT avatarurl FROM users WHERE username = username  ';Shows all Avatars

Answer (score 0):

echo mysql_result($result,0,0);

this gives  only one avatarurl out.

That was the Solution Thanks for your time.